# Need Help on recover encrypted home directory after failed release update

Tags: encryption

Hy i have the problem that some files got corupted during a release update for xubuntu. I encrypted my home folder.

Now i took out my hdd from this laptop (with the broken os). and mounted it on my desktop maschine.

i found my **warped-passphrase** file and it seems it is **not corupted**.

So i tried to run **ecryptfs-recover-private** but it exits with the **error:
find: "/run/user/1000/gvfs": Keine Berechtigung (no rights to access)**

Can some one tell me how i get ecryptfs-recover-private to ignore this error?
Or how i can encrypt the home directory manually?

Answer (score 0):

I din't get the command discribed above to work.
But i found another way here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1597246&s=42da6f910fcad4beb3e9c95d8ffc4058&p=10374453#post10374453

i was able to mount but now i'm stuck that when i go to /mnt/

and do an ls it shows files and folders but ther are only ?? on all atributes
d?????????  ? ?        ?           ?            ? .adobe

I'll write a second question for this.